# How to fix Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.7

Hi i am trying to fix this issue when i run python3 brain.py below i get this error
Illegal instruction (core dumped)

```
from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
import os
execution_path=os.getcwd()

prediction = ImagePrediction()
prediction.setModelTypeAsSqueezeNet()
prediction.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path, "squeezenet_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5"))
prediction.loadModel()

predictions, probabilities = prediction.predictImage(os.path.join(execution_path, "giraffe.jpg"), result_count=5 )
for eachPrediction, eachProbability in zip(predictions, probabilities):
    print(eachPrediction , " : " , eachProbability)
```

I have tried to downgrade Tensorflow to 1.5.0 but then after i run that i get these errors

```
[ons mar 25 23:11:45] Jonathan@Whats next?:~/ReallySmartBrain$ pip3 install tensorflow==1.5.0
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.5.0 (from versions: 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0rc3, 1.15.0, 1.15.2, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0rc0, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0rc2, 2.1.0, 2.2.0rc0, 2.2.0rc1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.5.0
```

The other solution is to compile it from source code but i'don't have any idea to compile it from source code. 
Can i fix this anyway?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. It seems that this problem is for older CPUs. As you said, one solution is with a downgrade to tensorflow 1.5.0.

The other solution (that one that worked for me) is to build tensorflow from source.

I compiled the version 2.1.0, it took me around 25 hours with a Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  T2370  @ 1.73GHz and 2GB RAM.

You would need to install the proper version of Bazel. Find below the complete instructions from tensorflow:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

I needed to add a swap file of 4GB. Otherwise you will go out of memory during the compilation.

Anyway, I have uploaded my .whl file in case you don't want to expend 25 hours (or more) to compile your own file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ISgMcDiCw5W5MFvS5Zbme6pNBbA7xWMH

Comment: Thanks Federico should download this file and use cd to go into your files on which should file should go into if i downloaded it from your drive?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem with an old CPU on a vintage Mac OS now running Linux because no recent Mac OS can run on it. I've tried to compile from sources and got a bunch of problems (Bazel, compiler, flags, dependencies, ...). Finally, I've lost few hours to learn that could be a real nightmare. Good advice, don't even try it!