# How to run Tensorflow in Docker on Synology

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, synology

I'm trying to run Tensorflow in Docker on my Synology DS but it will not start.

I successfully installed the CPU-only version from PIP:

```
root@cc99caafbb07:/home/# pip3 install tensorflow-cpu                                                                  
-> Collecting tensorflow-cpu                                                                                                      
-> Using cached tensorflow_cpu-2.3.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (137.4 MB) 
-> Installing collected packages: tensorflow-cpu                                                                                  
-> Successfully installed tensorflow-cpu-2.3.1
```

But, when I check the installation, I get an error:

```
root@cc99caafbb07:/home# python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf;'                                                        
-> Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Does anyone know how can I solve the issue?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61163264/12451425

Comment: My guess is celeron CPU does not have the required Advanced Vector Extensions (AVX).